# Python make new wrapper class that inherits all methods

Tags: python

from https://github.com/openai/gym/blob/master/gym/core.py:

```
class Wrapper(Env):
    r"""Wraps the environment to allow a modular transformation.
    This class is the base class for all wrappers. The subclass could override
    some methods to change the behavior of the original environment without touching the
    original code.
    .. note::
        Don't forget to call ``super().__init__(env)`` if the subclass overrides :meth:`__init__`.
    """
    def __init__(self, env):
        self.env = env
        self.action_space = self.env.action_space
        self.observation_space = self.env.observation_space
        self.reward_range = self.env.reward_range
        self.metadata = self.env.metadata

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        if name.startswith('_'):
            raise AttributeError("attempted to get missing private attribute '{}'".format(name))
        return getattr(self.env, name)

    @property
    def spec(self):
        return self.env.spec

    @classmethod
    def class_name(cls):
        return cls.__name__

    def step(self, action):
        return self.env.step(action)

    def reset(self, **kwargs):
        return self.env.reset(**kwargs)

    def render(self, mode='human', **kwargs):
        return self.env.render(mode, **kwargs)

    def close(self):
        return self.env.close()

    def seed(self, seed=None):
        return self.env.seed(seed)

    def compute_reward(self, achieved_goal, desired_goal, info):
        return self.env.compute_reward(achieved_goal, desired_goal, info)
```

Is there any way to automatically inherit the "Env" class methods, without manually defining them as they did here? Similar to how get_attr automatically grabs all the attributes, can we automatically grab all the methods?

Comment: Methods *are* sttributes. The `__getattr__` implementation already does all you need.

Comment: So why do they rewrite the step, reset etc methods you see above?

Comment: Note however that it doesn't make sense for this class to *inherit* Env; it's delegating to its attribute, ie composition rather than inheritance.

Comment: Who knows. Maybe it's just not good code?

Comment: This implementation is a bit weird. This class already subclasses `Env`, so why does it need an `env` attribute (which I assume is an instance of `Env`)? You very rarely need both inheritance and composition.